Issue with FTD2XX_NET.cs wrapper on Jetson Orin AGX (serial number and description empty)
I am experiencing an issue with the FTD2XX_NET.cs wrapper provided by FTDI Chip. This wrapper supports both Windows and Linux using conditional compilation directives (#IF WINDOWS and #IF LINUX) to load the appropriate library (ftd2xx.dll or libftd2xx.so).
The wrapper is available on the official FTDI support page in the "Code Examples" section under "C# Examples.".

On Windows (x64, version 2.12.36.4 of ftd2xx.dll), everything works correctly.

On Jetson Orin AGX (Ubuntu 22.04, ARM64, version 1.4.27 of libftd2xx.so), the wrapper doesn't retrieve the serial number or description of FTDI devices. Other fields are also empty, but the serial number and description are the fields I need


I have two projects in .NET7:

Class library: Contains the FTD2XX_NET.cs wrapper.

Console application: Tests the wrapper functionality.


To test on Jetson, I publish the application using the following command:
dotnet publish -c LINUX -r ubuntu.22.04-arm64 --self-contained -o ./publish
Here is the code I am using for testing:
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using FTDI;

Console.WriteLine("FTDI CONSOLE TEST APP");

UInt32 ftdiDeviceCount = 0;
FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;

// Create new instance of the FTDI device class
FTDIDevice myFtdiDevice = new FTDIDevice();

// Determine the number of FTDI devices connected to the machine
ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftdiDeviceCount);
// Check status
if (ftStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of FTDI devices: " + ftdiDeviceCount.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to get number of devices {" + ftdiDeviceCount + "} (" + ftStatus + ")");
    Console.ReadKey();
    return;
}

// If no devices available, return
if (ftdiDeviceCount == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to get number of devices {" + ftdiDeviceCount + "} (" + ftStatus.ToString() + ")");
    Console.ReadKey();
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Get the number of devices {" + ftdiDeviceCount + "} (" + ftStatus.ToString() + ")");
// Allocate storage for device info list
FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] ftdiDeviceList = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[ftdiDeviceCount];

// Populate our device list
ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetDeviceList(ftdiDeviceList);

if (ftStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
{
    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < ftdiDeviceCount; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device Index: " + i.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Flags: " + String.Format("{0:x}", ftdiDeviceList[i].Flags));
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + ftdiDeviceList[i].Type.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + String.Format("{0:x}", ftdiDeviceList[i].ID));
        Console.WriteLine("Location ID: " + String.Format("{0:x}", ftdiDeviceList[i].LocId));
        Console.WriteLine("Serial Number: " + ftdiDeviceList[i].SerialNumber.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Description: " + ftdiDeviceList[i].Description.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

Behavior:

On Windows, the console app correctly displays the serial number and description of connected FTDI devices:


On Jetson, both fields are empty:



Modified GetDeviceList Method for Debugging on Ubuntu:
To debug, I modified the GetDeviceList method in the wrapper (original available in the wrapper download) to throw an exception and log the contents of the sernum and desc byte arrays:
public FT_STATUS GetDeviceList(FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] devicelist)
{
    // Initialize ftStatus with a non-successful value
    FT_STATUS ftStatus = FT_STATUS.FT_INVALID_HANDLE;
    FT_ERROR ftErrorCondition = FT_ERROR.FT_NO_ERROR;

    UInt32 devcount = 0;

    // Delegates for FTDI functions
    tFT_CreateDeviceInfoList FT_CreateDeviceInfoList =
        (tFT_CreateDeviceInfoList)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(FTDILib.Instance.pFT_CreateDeviceInfoList, typeof(tFT_CreateDeviceInfoList));
    tFT_GetDeviceInfoDetail FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail =
        (tFT_GetDeviceInfoDetail)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(FTDILib.Instance.pFT_GetDeviceInfoDetail, typeof(tFT_GetDeviceInfoDetail));

    // Call FT_CreateDeviceInfoList
    ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(ref devcount);

    // Initialize byte arrays
    byte[] sernum = new byte[32];
    byte[] desc = new byte[64];

    if (devcount > 0)
    {
        // Check if the devicelist buffer is large enough
        if (devicelist.Length < devcount)
        {
            ftErrorCondition = FT_ERROR.FT_BUFFER_SIZE;
            ErrorHandler(ftStatus, ftErrorCondition);
        }

        for (UInt32 i = 0; i < devcount; i++)
        {
            devicelist[i] = new FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE();

            // Call FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail
            ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail(i, ref devicelist[i].Flags, ref devicelist[i].Type, ref devicelist[i].ID, ref devicelist[i].LocId, sernum, desc, ref devicelist[i].ftHandle);

            // Verify the call status
            if (ftStatus != FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail failed for index {i}. Status: {ftStatus}");
            }

            // Include the content and length of the arrays in the exception
            string sernumContent = string.Join(" ", sernum.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
            string descContent = string.Join(" ", desc.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));

            throw new InvalidOperationException($@"
                FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail executed in Ubuntu.
                Index: {i}
                Status: {ftStatus}
                Content of sernum: {sernumContent}
                Length of sernum: {sernum.Length}
                Content of desc: {descContent}
                Length of desc: {desc.Length}");
        }
    }

    return ftStatus;
}

Results:
On Windows, the sernum and desc arrays come pre-filled:

On Jetson, the sernum and desc arrays are filled with zeros:

Additional Test:
Using the example program included in the Linux driver (1.4.27 ARMv8 hard-float), the serial number and description are displayed correctly:

This suggests that the issue lies in the interaction between the wrapper and libftd2xx.so.
Question:
What could be causing the wrapper to fail on Jetson Orin AGX while the example program included in the Linux driver (1.4.27 ARMv8 hard-float) works? Both the wrapper and the example use the same version of the library (libftd2xx.so).
Could this be related to:

Differences in how the wrapper handles memory or string encoding on ARMv8 compared to x64?

Missing environment variables or dependencies specific to Jetson Orin AGX or Ubuntu 22.04?

The way the wrapper manages unmanaged resources (e.g., byte arrays or memory buffers) for the ARM64 architecture?


If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has suggestions on how to debug this further, I would greatly appreciate the input.
Thank you!
Update:
When I add sudo to the command during publishing, the result remains the same:
sudo dotnet publish -c LINUX -r ubuntu.22.04-arm64 --self-contained -o ./publish

